# Efficient method to check for existence of key in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In hyperledger fabric chaincode I am interested in checking for a condition while entering a record that , a new record with the same key should not be entered. Now for that I need to cross check my ledger and check if isDelete flag is true or false. Now the problem here is I need to use

```
resultsIterator, err := stub.GetHistoryForKey(key)
```

and then iterate over resultsIterator and check for isdelete flag and break the loop once I find that key had multiple values over the time. But here in the code the fucntion stub.GetHistoryForKey(key), itself might take lot of time of while scanning the whole ledger. So is there any way to efficient way to check scenario where I can check that the new key didnot exist before ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go ahead and safely use **stub.GetHistoryForKey(key)** to fulfil your requirement. Contrary to your belief, Fabric does not iterate over each block to get the history for a key.

It maintains a separate indexed database [implemented in Go Level DB] to store the history of all keys in the Block storage.

The index points to blocks and transactions within the block which modified a given key. The ledger exposes the following API to endorser which are then exposed as chaincode APIs.

```
// GetHistoryForKey retrieves the history of values for a key.
// The returned ResultsIterator contains results of type *KeyModification which is defined in protos/ledger/queryresult.
GetHistoryForKey(namespace string, key string) (commonledger.ResultsIterator, error)
```

For a given key, the above API returns historical values of the key, time at when the transaction which created/modified was issued, and whether it is a delete operation.    For implementation details of above function please refer to:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.2/core/ledger/kvledger/history/historydb/historyleveldb/historyleveldb_query_executer.go

Comment: Sigh of relief !! phew ! Thanks :)